# Scala FlatMap returning a vector instead of a String

Tags: string, scala, flatmap

I am following martin odesky course. And there is example where he applies flatMap to String and gets a string in return but I am getting a Vector. Here is the code that I am using

```
val str = "Hello"
println(str flatMap (x => List("." , x)))

output: Vector(., H, ., e, ., l, ., l, ., o)
outputExpected: .H.e.l.l.o.w
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`"."` is a `String` while `'.'` is a `Char`.

`List('.', x)` is a `List[Char]` (if `x` is a `Char`) which can be flattened to a `String`.

`List(".", x)` is a `List[Any]` (if `x` is not a `String`) which cannot be flattened to a `String`.

---

**UPDATE** -- This behavior has changed as of Scala 2.13.0.

```
"abc".flatMap(c => List('.', c))
//Scala 2.12.x returns String
//Scala 2.13.x returns IndexedSeq[Char] (REPL interprets as Vector)
```

This might be to insure a more consistent translation:

```
"abc".map(c => List('.', c)).flatten
//always returns IndexedSeq[Char]
```

Comment: that's great insight answer, scala is fun only if you know

Comment: `"."` is a `String` while `'.'` is a `Char` == true, but no matter which option I use, I get a `Vector` as a result (with Scala 2.13.6)

Answer (score 1):

A string is a collection of characters, not a collection of strings. So when you use `flatMap` to create a collection of characters, it'll choose `String` as the type of collection, but when you create a collection of strings, it can't use `String`, so it has to use `Vector` instead.